# Running a sandbox inside a virtual machine inside my OS

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation, sandbox, sandboxie

is that even possible?
As you may know, x64 microsoft system cannot ensure sandboxes/VM isolation.

The problem is that a stock Windows kernel does not provide all the facilities necessary to implement a security solution such as Sandboxie. On 32-bit Windows, Sandboxie can dynamically enhance the Windows kernel to provide the missing functionality. This was not initially possible on 64-bit Windows, due to the Kernel Patch Protection feature.

So, can I virtualise a Windows 7 32bits inside my windows x64 then put sanboxie inside this virtualised windows 7 32 bits?

sandboxie---[no leak]--->windows 7 32 bits------[leak possible]----->windows 7 x64

thanks

Comment: What makes you think Sandboxie is more secure than a virtual machine?

Comment: Nothing, it's just easier to use.

But sandboxie or not a VM hosted on a x64 system can leak.

Comment: "a VM hosted on a x64 system can leak" - do you have a reference for that?

Comment: http://www.sandboxie.com/index.php?ExperimentalProtection, KIS2013 removed their sandbox feature because of that

Comment: That link only describes some issues with Sandboxie under 64-bit Windows - I'm not sure how it relates to the security of a full virtual machine like VMware etc. ?

Comment: because it's not a limitation on the sandbox side but on microsoft side. as I said, even kaspersky remover their sandbox feature.

Comment: It sounds like you may not understand the difference between a sandbox and a virtual machine.

Comment: This question makes no sense. Why don't you just run VMWare within Sandboxie? There is no guarantee that Sandboxie doesn't have a bug within it. Your proof of "VM hosted on a x64 system can leak" is a promotional page for a paid product? You have no idea the reason KIS2013 removed a feature since you don't work for that company.  What evidence do you have that its "not possible" it can leak on 32-bit Sandboxie like all software has bugs.  **I guarantee you its possible, because some bug exists, that makes it possible **

Comment: I thought a sandbox was the same as a VM, so if a sandbox can leak then a VM can too.

therefore there would be no point to run a VM in sandboxie because id the VM leak inside sanboxie then the sandboxie can leak what has been leaked inside my OS.

Just google it and you will see that running any kind of sandbox inside a windows x64 is not secure.

Comment: Is what even possible, running a program in a VM? Of course. Doing so is no different than using multiple prophylactics at a time: it does indeed increase protection, but comes at some level of cost. As with all security measures, it depends on your specific situation whether it will be worth it or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can, but I wouldn't recommend doing so (with such "chained" solutions you're usually sacrificing lots of performance on the way, even with hardware virtualization being available).

It might be interesting to know what you're trying to do requiring sandboxie.